# CSS float not formatting properly

Tags: css

I have two divs that I want listed next to each other, but the formatting ends up all wrong?

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gLcag72p/)

```
<div class="pull-right" style="width:400px;">
  <div style="float:left; margin-right:90px;">
    <b>Registered owners</b>
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_unitRegOwners">Robert<br /></div>
  </div>
 <div>
    <b>Registered tenants</b>
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_unitRegTenants">Jenny Garth<br />Mike Mechanic<br />Joe Rogan<br />Test Test<br />John Doe<br /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Naturally, the Registered Owners should only have the name Robert under it, the rest should be listed under Registered Tenants, but for some reason only the first tenant is here she is supposed to be, and the rest ends up under Owners? its like the div is wrapping or something?

(please ignore the server side tags and the classes, it is the same even if you remove them)

Help appreciated!

Comment: Your fiddle appears to be working as expected. All tenants are listed correctly. You probably need to show more context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing what the desired outcome is, but I think you need to float the element it is supposed to be side by side with as well:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLcag72p/1/)

```
<div class="pull-right" style="width:400px;">
  <div style="float:left; margin-right:90px;">
    <b>Registered owners</b>
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_unitRegOwners">Robert<br /></div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:200px; float: left;">
    <b>Registered tenants</b>
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_unitRegTenants">Jenny Garth<br />Mike Mechanic<br />Joe Rogan<br />Test Test<br />John Doe<br /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was definitely just a guess since you mentioned floats. Please be sure to construct a question that is easily understood in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your div that you want on the right side also needs to have "float: left" defined so that it floats against the right side of the Owners div:

```
<div class="pull-right" style="width:400px;">
  <div style="float:left; margin-right:90px;">
    <b>Registered owners</b>
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_unitRegOwners">Robert<br /></div>
  </div>
 <div style="float:left;">
    <b>Registered tenants</b>
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_unitRegTenants">Jenny Garth<br />Mike Mechanic<br />Joe Rogan<br />Test Test<br />John Doe<br /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gLcag72p/2/

The contents of the Tenants div was wrapping around the Owners div, as you said, because only the Owners div had a float defined. So that div was being displayed pull-quote style with everything else wrapping around it.